# How to stop browser from rejecting my downloads?

Tags: web-hosting, google-chrome

I have a portfolio site where I am trying to host some of my work, so people can download my work. Some of these files include exe executables, and some are `.jar` executables, which are run through batch.

When a user tries to download my apps, it says that the file is not commonly downloaded and may be harmful, and therefore blocks the download. If I zip the folders, it still does the same thing. Any format I choose, still blocks the downloads.

How can I stop chrome from doing this. Is there a way I can verify my files so they will be considered as trusted?

Comment: Browser side, done to protect the user as this is commonly used to deliver malware, you have no control and I don't want you to be able to bypass it. Especially with zip files... No Cryptolocker delivery enablement here please. Choose another method of delivery.

Comment: what delivery method can I use then.

Comment: nope you have no control over this and for good reason

Answer (score 1):

All the options you need to change are done client side only.

[image: Chrome Download Options]

The Checkbox in the Circle must be checked, which will ask a user, where the file should be stored.  After storing it, the user will still be warned that the file is dangerous, and if the user chooses discard, the file is still deleted.

---

**Update**
The reason jar files are considered malicious is because the **J** ava **AR** chive can contain an "executable" file.  If that file contains malicious code, when clicking it, you allow the code to run.  Browsers would rather air on the side of caution then allow data corruption/destruction by malicious code.  In order to fix this you must find an approved browser file type.  See this [Google Groups Post on Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r-9JQIboUmc)

Comment: Thing is I don't want people to think my downloads are malicious :(

Comment: I understand, but regardless, the settings for that are all client side.  The only thing the server controls is the MIME Types, and all that does is tell the client browser to tell the users PC what application to use to open a file.

Comment: Thank's fr your help. I found out that MediaFire lets me hsot the download without any problems. I still don't get why it's ok for MediaFire to host it and not me. I don't really mind though, i'm just curious.

Comment: Because you're hosting it without an SSL certificate

Answer (score 0):

I have equally been frustrated by this warning, and without going into a rant about how ridiculous the whole thing is, I will share the solution that worked for me.

I have found that double zipping got rid of the warning right away- **zip** your files, then **zip** the resulting **zip** file, et voila, the warning will disappear.

The user will have to unzip 2 files to get to your files, but that is a much lesser inconvenience than the dangerous warning.